# Why doesn't FTP request allow "%20"?

Tags: vb.net, ftpwebrequest

I am making an FTP request and whenever the parameter `remoteFilePath` contains a string with "%20" I get an error that the file cannot be found. How can I get around this?

```
Dim remoteFileWriteTime As Date = Ftp.GetDateTimeStamp(remoteFilePath).ToLocalTime()
```

Note: I am not responsible for naming the files as it is not my server.

Comment: Does the filename _actually_ contain a `%`?  `%20` is probably being interpreted as a space - sounds like you have an encoding issue somewhere along the way.

Comment: The filename actually does contain "%".

Comment: @Hooplehead24 you really shouldn't use a `%` character in file names. Its one of those characters best to avoid in filenames.

Comment: @Fred Why?  It's a perfectly valid character in a filename.  So long as you understand the issues around escaping characters properly there's no problem.  The same could be said of many other characters in other situations.  Properly escaping strings should be within the remit of any decent developer.

Comment: @Fred I agree but I am not the one creating the files unfortunately.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes it is a perfectly valid character but it is one of those characters that can cause problems if you do not know how to handle them.  Without them you have no issue to handle in the first place. The same can be said for many other characters.  For example the % character can be used as a wildcard and while you can escape any special characters it makes total sense to avoid using them where ever you can. As you said "So long as you understand the issues around escaping characters properly", clearly not everyone does.

Comment: I admit it, I do not know how to deal with this issue. This is why I asked the question. If I cannot rename the files, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This may just be a matter of passing the filename through `Uri.EscapeDataString`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the filename using this:

```
Dim baseUri as String = "ftp://SomeFtpServer/"
Dim file as String = "Strangely%20Named%20File.pdf"
Dim myUri as String = baseUri & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file)
Dim remoteFileWriteTime As Date = Ftp.GetDateTimeStamp(myUri).ToLocalTime()
```

You might need to encode using `Uri.EscapeDataString` if HttpUtility isn't encoding it correctly. I'm not sure exactly which encoding scheme FTP expects offhand.